# Getting FileNotFoundException on Input Stream in Android

Tags: c#, android, wcf

i've been trying to get data response from WCF to Android, but getting error during connect to WCF.

**Call HttpHandler**

```
HttpHandler sh = new HttpHandler();
    String baseurl = "http://10.0.2.2:8080/Service1.svc/ViewAllStudent";
    String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(baseurl);
    Log.e(TAG, "Response from url: " + jsonStr);
```

**HttpHandler.java**

```
public String makeServiceCall(String reqUrl) {
    String response = null;
    try {
        URL url = new URL(reqUrl);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        // read the response
        InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(conn.getInputStream());
        response = convertStreamToString(in);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.e(TAG, "MalformedURLException: " + e.getMessage());
    } catch (ProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.e(TAG, "ProtocolException: " + e.getMessage());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.e(TAG, "IOException: " + e.getMessage());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.e(TAG, "Exception: " + e.getMessage());
    }
    return response;
}

private String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    String line;
    try {
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line).append('\n');
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            is.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    return sb.toString();
}
```

**Logcat**

```
05-08 00:39:10.052 3763-3780/? W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://10.0.2.2:8080/Service1.svc/ViewAllStudent
05-08 00:39:10.052 3763-3780/? W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:250)
05-08 00:39:10.052 3763-3780/? W/System.err:     at json.aprivate.sch.diesirepurejson.HttpHandler.makeServiceCall(HttpHandler.java:31)
05-08 00:39:10.052 3763-3780/? W/System.err:     at json.aprivate.sch.diesirepurejson.MainActivity$GetContacts.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:50)
05-08 00:39:10.052 3763-3780/? W/System.err:     at json.aprivate.sch.diesirepurejson.MainActivity$GetContacts.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:37)
05-08 00:39:10.052 3763-3780/? W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:305)
05-08 00:39:10.052 3763-3780/? W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
05-08 00:39:10.052 3763-3780/? W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:243)
05-08 00:39:10.052 3763-3780/? W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
05-08 00:39:10.052 3763-3780/? W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
05-08 00:39:10.052 3763-3780/? W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
05-08 00:39:10.052 3763-3780/? E/HttpHandler: IOException: http://10.0.2.2:8080/Service1.svc/ViewAllStudent
05-08 00:39:10.052 3763-3780/? E/MainActivity: Response from url: null
05-08 00:39:10.052 3763-3780/? E/MainActivity: Couldn't get json from server.
```

i always getting  FileNotFoudException from URL even though i was try the URL on postman and works properly. What's wrong of my code, any idea?

Comment: For all your `Log.e()` calls, pass `e` as the third parameter. Then, examine the full Java stack trace associated with your `IOException`.

Comment: `always getting null response from URL.`. No. You always have an IOException. You do not get a response at all. And what all can happen in convertStreamToSting you are not showing us.

Comment: @CommonsWare i getting FileNotFoundException

Comment: @greenapps ah sorry i'll edit it

Comment: That indicates that your server is returning an HTTP 404 response for that URL.

Comment: @CommonsWare any idea how to fix that? This is my first time consume wcf to android so i don't really know, sorry.

Comment: I would start by testing that URL outside of Android (i.e., does it work as `http://localhost:8080/Service1.svc/ViewAllStudent` on your development machine?)

Comment: @CommonsWare yes, the service works fine on Postman. Meanwhile in Android give that result, changed 10.0.2.2 into localhost / 127.0.0.1 give result connection refused.

Comment: If you are running this on an emulator on the same machine as the server, `10.0.2.2` is the correct address. You will need to check the server logs and see if there is any indication why the server is returning a 404.